# consulta anidada en codeigniter con mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

buenas. tengo una consulta que ya funciona en mysql pero no he podido hacerla funcionar en mi modelo de codeigniter exactamente tengo problemas de sintaxis como podria plasmar dicha consulta:

```
select t1.id_tabla1 as , t1.condicion,
        greatest(coalesce(max(t1.Fecha), 0),coalesce(max(t2.Fecha), 0), coalesce(max(t3.Fecha), 0), coalesce(max(t4.Fecha), 0)) as 'max_fecha'
  from tabla1 t1
  left join tabla2 t2
    on t2.id_tabla2 = t1.id_tabla1
  left join tabla3 t3
    on t3.id_tabla3 = t1.id_tabla1
  left join tabla t4
    on t4.id_tabla4 = t1.id_tabla1
 group by t1.id_tabla1
```

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que intentaste en codeigniter?

Comment: Tenia el mismo problema con codeigniter, la solucion fue crear una vista (o tambien sirve un Procedimiento Almacenado) y llamarla desde el modelo. Al parecer codeigniter se marea con la sintaxis al hacer joins (ya se con el helper para las querys o directamente)

Answer (score 1):

Te monto la query builder para Codeigniter según la que pones, tenías un error en el select aparecía un as sin alias al principio.

```
$this->db->select(t1.id_tabla1 , t1.condicion, greatest(coalesce(max(t1.Fecha), 0),coalesce(max(tabla2.Fecha), 0), coalesce(max(tabla3.Fecha), 0), coalesce(max(tabla4.Fecha), 0)) as 'max_fecha');
$this->db->join("tabla2", "tabla2.id_tabla2 = t1.id_tabla1", 'left');
$this->db->join("tabla3", "tabla3.id_tabla3 = t1.id_tabla1", 'left');
$this->db->join("tabla4", "tabla4 .id_tabla4 = t1.id_tabla1", 'left');
$this->db->group_by('t1.id_tabla1');
$this->db->get('tabla1 as t1');
```